# Dir folder and subfolder shows result in one folder, but not other folder

Tags: vb.net

Just trying to learn VB.net.
Making something that lists all files an folders in folder and subfolder.
Got a testfolder in root C:\ with a 2 subfolders and som files in al folders.
On execution listbox is filled with al files an folders including subfolders an files in subfolders.
But.. 
If id choose a folder on G:\ things get strange, and I only get A few folders or files listed

This is my first question here,so if if screw up in telling you, I am sorry

```
    Public Class Form1
Dim R As IO.StreamReader
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Listfiles(Me.FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
End Sub

Public Sub Listfiles(ByVal Pad As String)

    Dim DirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Pad)
    Dim FileObject As IO.FileSystemInfo
    Dim strBESTAND As String


    For Each FileObject In DirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
        'if FileObject is a folder
        If FileObject.Attributes = IO.FileAttributes.Directory Then             '


            Listfiles(FileObject.FullName)
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(FileObject.FullName)
        Else
            strBESTAND = (FileObject.FullName)

            Dim information = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(strBESTAND)

            ' If extention matches ..........
            Dim strEXTENTIE As String
            'if extentie is tikt in checkedlistbox 
            For i As Integer = 0 To (CheckedListBoxEXTENTIES.CheckedItems.Count - 1)  ' iterate on checked items
                'only us ticked items
                strEXTENTIE = ((CheckedListBoxEXTENTIES.GetItemText(CheckedListBoxEXTENTIES.CheckedItems(i)).ToString))
                If information.Extension = "." & strEXTENTIE Then
                    strBESTAND = information.Name
                    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(FileObject.Name)

                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string comparisons are case sensitive by default. You will miss extensions having another case as in the CheckedListBox. Use

```
If String.Compare(information.Extension, "." & strEXTENTIE, _
                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0 Then
```

But it would be more efficient if you prepared the extensions before browsing the folders

```
'Outside of subroutines
Dim extensions As New HashSet(Of String)()

'In Button1_Click before calling Listfiles
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBoxEXTENTIES.CheckedItems.Count - 1
    extensions.Add("." &  _
      CheckedListBoxEXTENTIES.CheckedItems(i).ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
Next
```

Then you can check the extensions like this, without having to loop through the CheckedListBox for each file.

```
If extensions.Contains(information.Extension.ToLowerInvariant()) Then
```

Comment: Started a new project, minimal code.
Used filesystem properties  and a single variable ( t0 be able to choose other folder to look in..
Folder and subfolders were found and sought thru, but....One folder was identified as a file??
Looked at permissions, OK
Looked at properties, are equal to other found subfolders

Comment: See this video: [Create a Simple Visual Basic Application in Visual Studio 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njyrhf-wd70)

Comment: Thank you
Been away for a while, just noticed a reminder in my mailbox.
The question can be considerd closed

Comment: In order to close the question, click the check mark (to the left of) of the accepted answer